# C# - Replace string in text file between certain values

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

Im having issues trying to figure out how I can replace an IP address in a configuration file for an application. the IP is in multiple different config files such as the below

```
[Connection]
### Address of the database server
DBServer=10.10.102.114
### Name of the database
DBData=DB1
```

I need to be able to read the file, then search for a string (for this file it would be "DBServer=") and have it replace the string between what was searched for and a secondary string or end of line character as in this example

I can only seem to find ways to find and replace the string that was found, but the IP is different in every install so I cant reliably search for the IP directly

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try searching for `ini file parser c#`.

Comment: Your are asking the wrong question. You do not want to replace an ip address. You do want to change the host value for DBServer. Well at the end it seems like you are just changing an ip address, but the steps before that end are totally different

Comment: that is one of many files I need to edit, it's the only .ini so my question is correct as i need to replace the IP address in other config files that are not .ini files. So my question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases that you know only pattern, you should use regular expression. It is very easy to use. 
You need add this namespace:

```
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Then define your pattern like:

```
    string pattern=@"DBServer=(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})";
    Regex regex=new Regex(pattern);
    var match = regex.Match("YOUR_INPUT_STRING");
    string result;
    if(match.Success)
        if(match.Groups.Count > 0)
            result=match.Group[1].Value;
```

Comment: For get more information see this link.    [link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, finally got it to work using the below.....it might not be the best practice but seems to work

```
string line;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\config.ini"))
{
     line = sr.ReadToEnd();
}


Regex x = new Regex("(\\DBServer\\=)(.*?)(\n|\r|\r\n)");
string repl = IP;
string Result = x.Replace(line, "DBServer=" + repl + "$3");
using (StreamWriter writer =
     new StreamWriter(@"C:\config.ini"))
{
     writer.Write(Result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That file is an `.ini` file. They have largely fallen out of fashion these days in favour of XML or, more recently, JSON config files.

I recommend using the [ini-parser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ini-parser/) NuGet package.

You can use it like so to update the DBServer value:

```
string iniFile = @"test.ini";
var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
IniData data = null;
data = parser.ReadFile(iniFile);
data.Sections["Connection"]["DBServer"] = "newValue";
parser.WriteFile(iniFile, data);
```